# Linq group by return always values

Tags: c#, linq

I have this small code and I wanna return Today and count always with or not values.

```
DateRange dateRangeLastWeek = DateRange.LastWeek(DateTime.Now);

var caseCounts = db.Find(x => x.FinishDate.HasValue)
                .Where(c => c.FinishDate.Value.Date == dateRangeLastWeek.Today.Date || 
                (c.FinishDate.Value.Date >= dateRangeLastWeek.Start && c.FinishDate.Value.Date <= dateRangeLastWeek.End))
                .GroupBy(c => c.FinishDate.Value.Date == dateRangeLastWeek.Today.Date ? "Today" : "Last Week")
                .Select(g => new JsonChartModel
                {
                      Name = g.Key,
                      Value = g.Count() 
                });
```

In this case I wanna return:

- Today : 10
- Last Week: 0

Comment: Please reframe your questions so that we can get what is actually asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really elegant, but you could use an Union with default Values, and select the max between default and returned values.

```
var defaultValues = new List<JsonChartModel> {
   new JsonChartModel{Name = "Today", Value = 0},
   new JsonChartModel{Name = "Last Week", Value = 0}
};

var result = <YourQuery>.ToList().Union(defaultValues)
             .GroupBy(m => m.Name)
             .Select(g => new JsonChartModel) {
                Name = g.Key,
                Value = g.Max(x => x.Value)
             });
```